# PfSense and redirecting DNS requests

Tags: dns, pfsense

I set **DNS Resolver** as my DNS service in my pfsense v. 2.4.5, set also pfsense local IP address (127.0.1.1, actually 192.168.5.1) as my only dns server, letting Resolver to send dns request to the Dns root servers directly.
I was then wondering what happens if any clients in my LAN set dns IP address in thier network card proprieties to, say, bypass pfsense Resolver and send queries to external resolvers.
So, I set this rules:

https://pfsense-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dns/blocking-dns-queries-to-external-resolvers.html

They work but also keep clients from getting access to internet if they set their own dns servers.

I then tried this NAT rule:

https://pfsense-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dns/redirecting-all-dns-requests-to-pfsense.html

But I don't know if it works as it is stated in the article.
After setting dns servers in my pc network card proprieties (8.8.4.4), I run pfsense **Packet Capture** which apprently shows that dns requests are sent and get responded directly by 8.8.4.4.
A few nslookups show the same
I don't understand what exactly is going on, and how to make sure that the NAT rule above is doing its job properly.

Comment: Which interface did you run the packet capture on?

Comment: @user1686 on the LAN interface.

Comment: Well that sounds completely normal then? If the computer tried to contact 8.8.4.4, the replies _have_ to say they're from 8.8.4.4 as well, whether they're real or whether they're NATed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAT is automatically applied in both directions. If the computer sends packets to 8.8.4.4 and pfSense redirects them to another address, it *must* apply the exact opposite change to responses coming back to the computer – otherwise the computer wouldn't recognize it as belonging to the same conversation.

So even if the response was actually generated by your local resolver, pfSense will rewrite its source to say "8.8.4.4" to match the original request.

The easiest way to determine whether your NAT works is to capture the same traffic on **both** LAN and WAN interfaces. If the responses come from the "real" 8.8.4.4 then they will arrive at the WAN interface first, before going out to the LAN. But if your redirection works and they were produced by the local resolver, then the packets will just appear on the LAN side out of nowhere *without* a corresponding WAN packet.

Alternatively: tell the computer to use a DNS server address that *isn't* a real DNS server. (For example, 192.0.2.x is the usual "dummy address" range and cannot possibly respond to DNS queries.) If the computer somehow receives responses even after querying a nonexistent server, that's a sign of redirection working.

Comment: Yes, I see. Still a couple of (stupid) questions if you don't mind. 1) Is there any way to run both LAN and WAN Packet Capture at the same time? 2) I run dns leak test. It SEEMS to show my dns ISP server? Is it a root dns server maybe? How comes? Thanks again

Comment: 1) Yes but only as two separate captures – i.e. two separate windows or `tcpdump` processes. 2) Depends on what "upstreams" you've configured for the pfSense resolver.

Comment: "upstreams"? What do you mean? Thanks

Comment: I now noticed that you wrote the pfSense resolver will "send dns request to the Dns root servers directly" (no upstreams). In that case, the DNS leak test is simply detecting _you_, because your resolver will be directly contacting _each domain's_ nameservers directly.

Comment: (Note that DNS 'root' nameservers only provide authoritative service, not recursive. A recursive resolver such as 8.8.8.8 immediately provides a full answer, but the 'root' nameservers merely point you to the correct place and the client itself has to finish the job – meaning you cannot "hide" behind the 'root' nameservers, quite the opposite.)